# How to decrypt the encrypted data, in SHA256, of mysql database?

Tags: tls, passwords, java

I have some data in column of table of mysql database in the encrypted form applied with SHA-256. How to decrypt that data using Java?
I stuck at this since 4 days.

Please spend 5 minutes of your valuable time to provide code snippet to decrypt that code.

Comment: Took me less than 5 minutes to find this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316437/how-to-decrypt-sha-256-encrypted-string

Answer (score 6):

SHA-256 is a hash function. That means it *cannot* be decrypted. If the original data that was hashed is relatively small (and not salted), you could try [rainbowtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

Also see ["Difference between hashing a password and encrypting it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it)